# Input Type=Date Is not Displaying the initialized value

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have used FormIk for submitting and validating the data. When I am using Input type date for date of birth in my form The validations and all things work except for that. I want to show today's date and it is binding at backend somehow as it is not giving the issue, but I cannot see the date and only show dd-MMM-YYYY

I have used Yup for displaying the default value but still not working.
I have passed new date to model:

```
 const max = new Date();
this.state = {
      model: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        address: "",
        gender: "",
        dateOfBirth: max,
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        careerInterests: []
      }
    };
```

```
<Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={model}>
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              setFieldValue,
              setFieldTouched,
              handleSubmit
            } = props;
            return (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 <Field
                      value={values.dateOfBirth}
                      onChange={e => {
                        setFieldValue("dateOfBirth", e.target.value);
                      }}
                      type="date"
                      name="dateOfBirth"
                      placeholder="Enter date of birth"
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      className="help-block"
                      name="dateOfBirth"
                      component="div"
                    />
</Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
```

Value is in model but not displayed in frontend, If anyone can make any eg or sample. It will be very helpful

Comment: `<input type="date" />` expects the date to be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Format_of_a_valid_date_string) to pass an initial value to it. Are you absolutely sure you are formatting the value that way? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kvcwtn

Comment: Yeah, It works, Thanks for your kind and quick response. :)

Comment: For me the error was that if I don't provide an initial value for the input in that format YYYY-MM-DD, the input is not working any longer